# How to fix <ul>'s in footer that break in ie8 & ie9, but is perfect in ie7, FF, Safari & Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, html-lists

I'm having one hell of a headache trying to figure this out for myself, i've taught myself the code i know, so i very well could be missing a simple thing. But i greatly need you're help and appreciate it tremendously.

I obviously want my website to look the same across all browsers and this is a major mess, that i am struggling with.

The problem is easier to explain with pictures, as such i have a screen print from ie9 and ff to show you:

Firefox, Safari, Chrome & IE7

[How the footer and lists look in Firefox, Safari, Chrome & IE7](http://tshirtslut.com/ff.jpg)

IE9 & IE8 (the grey at the bottom is the body background)

[How the footer and lists look in IE9 & IE8](http://tshirtslut.com/ie.jpg)

Here is the html:

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="columncon">   
    <div class="column"> 
    <h5>From The Blog...</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Post 1<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Post 2<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Post 3<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Post 4<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Post 5<a/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <h5>Social</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Google +<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">RSS Subscribe<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">E-mail Subscribe<a/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <h5>Site Links</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Designer Resources<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit a T-Shirt<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sitemap<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us<a/></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>      
    <div class="column">    

    <h5>Site Links</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Designer Resources<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit a T-Shirt<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sitemap<a/></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us<a/></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
</div>    
<div id="siteinfo">
<p>&copy; 2011 <a href="http://www.tshirtslut.com">TShirtSlut.com</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#footer {
background: url(img/footerbg.png) 0 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 10px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
height:200px;
position:relative;
clear:both;
}   
#columncon {
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}   
.column {
float:left;
padding: 30px 25px 20px;
width: 200px;
}
.column ul {
    list-style:none;
}
    .column ul li {
        padding:2px 0;
    }
        .column ul li a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fff;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        .column ul li a:hover{
            color:#49E20E;
        }
.column h5 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff; text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
           }
   #siteinfo {
   text-align:center;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
color:#fff;
font-size:12px; 
    }
#siteinfo a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
#siteinfo a:hover {
    color:#49E20E;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

(apparently I'm not the best at inserting code XD)

Once again i truly will appreciate whoever can put this problem into context for me and allow me to solve this issue.

If you need anymore code, or info please ask and i shall get to it right away.

Thank you,

Mike

**UPDATE: I have fixed the anchor tags so they validate but am still left with a double footer and the heading of the first list still remaining in the "doubled" footer. Please follow URL for a picture:**

--http://tshirtslut.com/ie%28partially%20fixed%29.jpg--

Comment: does this work in IE? http://jsfiddle.net/RM7eG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is not valid. Replace all `<a/>` with `</a>`. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Thankyou, that helped but still leaves an issue. It has fixed the majority of the problem though.

Comment: Are you sure there is no more html validation error? Have you checked your website? Try this link: [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: you sir are a legend, 100% validated and now it works a treat!